# Mysql VIEW with explicit column datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I set the datatype of columns in a `mysql` `view`?

The following is incorrect:

```
CREATE VIEW person_view AS
SELECT 'Test' AS VARCHAR(20) person_firstname,
       person.age AS int(2) person_age
FROM person;
```

table person:

```
#firstname, lastname, age
john, doe, 8
jane, doe, 5
```

The example data will trigger the generation of `VARCHAR(4)` for firstname and `int(1)` for age. But in fact I want to support `VARCHAR(20)` and `int(2)` for those columns in the view.

Comment: Why? And can you give an example. Cast or convert would seem applicable.

Comment: @P.Salmon because depending on the source data, mysql will implicit create eg a `int(1) age` column even though I want `int(2)`.

Comment: so you want to LPAD  to n characters? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Comment: No, I just want to change the column length.

Comment: Share sample data and how you need to display.

Comment: You cannot define the data types in a view and mysql is very restrictive in the types that can be cast to (for example you cannot cast to int(2)) apart from anything else in int(2) the 2 is a display size the underlying type is still int. You could fiddle about with display sizes by padding or string manipulation (but that would change that would alter the data type). I'm quite curious to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @P.Salmon added an example.

Comment: Can you add the table definition for person please.(show create table person; and copy and paste result)

Comment: *I want to support VARCHAR(20) and int(2) for those columns in the view.* So what happens next? Just to display or any other process?

Comment: Other applications will select, update and delete on the view. Therefore, especially for *update*, I would want to have the max column size right.

Comment: `Update` will directly affect only the table it will not affect the `view`

Answer (score 3):

Try using CAST or CONVERT

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT CAST('Test' AS VARCHAR(20)) Column1 FROM mysource;
```

Comment: Would this have an impact on performance if every column is casted?

Comment: I had to do this with several SQL Server tables that weren't created properly and never noticed a performance hit.  But it may depend on the conversion being performed.  Some are probably more complex than others.

Comment: @Mark Wagoner you cannot cast to varchar see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast for permitted cast types.

Comment: also the SQL tag on this website does not mean SQL Server (MSSQL) ...

Answer (score 1):

A view just sits on top of the underlying table against which it was defined, so views normally do not allow us to change the table definition.  If, for example, you wanted to create a view which consisted only of the first 20 characters of some potentially larger `varchar` column, you could do so using `LEFT`, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS (
    SELECT LEFT(some_col, 20) AS some_col_short
    FROM mysource
)
```

But even here, we are not changing the definition of the table, only the way the underlying data is being viewed.

Comment: A view can return a new value such as "TRUE as am_i_generated". It ends up as an integer instead of as tinyint(1) so tools like jooq can't map it as a boolean.